# How can I write this query using TypeORM createQueryBuilder?

Tags: node.js, graphql, typeorm

I want to write this raw query using the TypeORM `createQueryBuilder`. How can I achieve this?

```
SELECT *
FROM Location l
INNER JOIN LocationType t ON l.TypeId = t.Id
LEFT JOIN Location p ON l.ParentId = p.Id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT locationId, SUM(Units) TotalUnits FROM ItemInventory GROUP BY LocationId) qty ON l.Id = qty.LocationId`
```

Comment: `createQueryBuilder` doesn't support raw joins as far as I know, you could create a [view-entity](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/view-entities.md) for the query